# Construct an ellipse given foci and a tangent line

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given the two foci of an ellipse and a tangent line of the ellipse, can one construct the ellipse with a compass and a straightedge?

[image: ellipse]

Comment: Using optical property of ellipses.

Comment: There is a unique ellipse if that is what you mean - if not when would you consider the ellipse constructed and with which instruments?

Comment: @NgChungTak Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MartinRattigan Question specified.

Comment: What do you mean by "construct the ellipse with a compass and a straightedge"? Constructing a point on the ellipse would be enough? Or you need a construction of the four vertices?

Comment: I didn't understand the comment "Question specified". Ng Chung Tak has posted a method of *drawing* the ellipse with a piece of string and presumably pins to fix the ends as implements. This may be what you meant by constructing the ellipse in which case I would suggest you accept the answer. Some methods of drawing ellipses are shown here: https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/MATHALGO/Ellipses.HTM. There is no method of tracing out exact ellipses by using ruler and compasses in the prescribed manner nor of practicably constructing more than a finite  number of points lying on the ellipse.

Comment: Incidentally, for a string and pins method, a loop tightened around pins at $A$ and $B$ and the point $C$ would allow the ellipse to be traced in a single path without the string catching on the pins and may be more practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are the two foci, $B'$ is the mirror image of $B$ about the tangent.  Now $AB'$ meets the tangent at $C$.  Construct the ellipse with string of length $AB'=AC+BC$ with its ends on foci $A$ and $B$.

[image]