# Shifting of axes in conic section

Tags: conic-sections

So I have an ellipse with foci $(1,-1)$ and $(2,-1)$ and $x+y=5$ as tangent at $(m,n)$ . I need to find out the value of $ \frac {1}{e^2} $ where $e$ is the eccentricity of ellipse.
Please don't solve the question.
My attempt: I tried to write equation of tangent in parametric form and compare coefficients but the number of unknown is more than the number of relations. I need the process to be followed . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I need to shift the axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $A=(1,-1)$ and $B=(2,-1)$ and $B'=(x',y')$ be the reflection of $B$ about $x+y=5$.

By $BB' \perp x+y=5$,

$$\frac{y'-(-1)}{x'-2}=1 \tag{1}$$

Equating perpendicular distances,
$$\frac{2+(-1)-5}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=-\frac{x'+y'-5}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}} \tag{2}$$

> After solving you could find $2a=AB'$, together with $2ae=AB$.

See also another answer of mine [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215903/construct-an-ellipse-given-foci-and-a-tangent-line/2216031#2216031).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shifting the axes so that the ellipse is centered on the origin is a good way to start. You can then use the fact that the tangents to the shifted ellipse with slope $m$ have equations $y=mx\pm\sqrt{m^2a^2+b^2}$ and the known focal distance to generate a system of equations in $a^2$ and $b^2$, from which the rest should be fairly straightforward.